# Do flex boxes cause rendering issues on Firefox?

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, flexbox, flicker

Does anyone know what could cause Firefox to flash the screen? It turns black for a short period of time. I think it's a "reflow" but I can't figure out what's causing it.

I tried disabled transitions, custom fonts, gradients, but it still happens.

Could it be flex boxes? Because I'm using them everywhere, and I noticed some lagging in FF after I switched to flex boxes.

Comment: We're going to need more to go on, can you make an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I replaced the flex boxes with floats and everything is smooth now. So it seems that firefox sucks when you have 20-30 nested flexboxes on the page, with flex-wrap :(

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/does-flexbox-have-a-performance-problem/

Comment: have you looked through some of the flexbugs? https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs

Comment: @deebs The slowdown reported by css tricks is caused by using old `display:box` not the new `display:flex`, which is reported to be on par with traditional float / block / table layout.

Comment: Have you tried disabling hardware acceleration? In options > advanced.

Comment: Why offer a bounty on a question that doesn't even give an example of a page showing this behaviour? If it has a clear example then maybe other people could benefit from it, but as it stands now sounds like you're just taking potshots in the dark hoping to hit something.

Comment: I tried making an example on jsfiddle but I cant reproduce it. It seems to happen only on pages that have lots of stuff in them. I cant just move my website to jsfiddle, sorry. The black screen and slowdowns appear when changes are made in the html with javascript

Comment: Is your website live somewhere that you can link us to?

Comment: look at the web inspector and see what element is flashing and why it's flashing i.e. is  firefox changing the background color from #fff to #000?

Comment: do you have a huge jQuery UI file?

Comment: @Alex www139 is right. Take a look at the web inspector made available through Firefox to look at the page's behavior. I read an article (interestingly enough) the other day that said web development should never be done without the inspector open. Here's a link to a tutorial https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector

Comment: Can you please clarify the deficiencies you find with the existing answers?

Answer (score 6):

I've had this same problem in the past.  If you have lots of elements with `display: flex` nested inside each other it essentially doubles the rendering time.

A solution that worked for me was using `display:-moz-box` instead of `display: flex`

Alternatively I'd recommend restructuring your HTML to reduce the level of nesting and make you markup as lean as possible

You can find out more information in [this bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=946167)

Comment: "using display:-moz-box instead of display: flex" Ouch. Talk about a serious regression.

Comment: Awesome. Your answer got my vote because of three things: an immediate solution (the CSS); a larger potential optimization fix ("de-nesting"); and a link to some documentation about the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:-

```
.container {
  display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
  display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly      works) */
  display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
  display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
  display: flex;             /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
}
```

Change the .container with the selector for which your are applying flex property.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are facing this same issue, but I've found that browsers will render commented out CSS in the stylesheet, then disabled it. I have a page that has a class with a commented out background-image, and it will load that image, flash it, then disable the CSS. Check in your styles for commented black background color possibly.

Comment: I use Chrome 40.0.2214.111

Comment: Just to help others on this issue, it is MUCH more prevalent when the page loads slower. It is not disabled until the document is rendered and ready.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried turning off hardware acceleration in your general settings?

could be a conflict with your video card.

The credible source being that flex boxes explicity take advantage of hardware acceleration to function.

Answer (score 0):

Option -> Advanced ->General -> turning off hardware acceleration -> ok

[image]